# TextFormField value disappear and How to get textFormField value?

Tags: flutter, dart

***Please help for my 2 questions.***

**1st Question. Why text value disappear?**[FIXED] by @Praneeth
I added gif
[please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pivoJ.gif)

I used this way my code,

In my widget I called `UsernameTextField` class.
Widget looks like this,

> Widget build > WillPopScope > Scaffold > Form > ListView > children>
>   Container (below container) I added `key: _scaffoldKey,` and  `key: formKey,` also.

```
 Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                child: UsernameTextField(),
              ),
```

**UsernameTextField()**

```
class UsernameTextField extends StatefulWidget{
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return UsernameTextFieldState(usernameController);
  }
}

class UsernameTextFieldState extends State<UsernameTextField>{
  final usernameController;
  UsernameTextFieldState(this.usernameController);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppTextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          labelText: AppTranslations.of(context)
              .text("loginpage_username"),
        ),
        myController: usernameController,
        textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress
    );
  }
}
```

**AppTextField() class,** I used this class for my every TextField Widget

```
class AppTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final InputDecoration decoration;
  final myController;
  final TextInputType textInputType;
  AppTextField({
    this.decoration,
    this.myController,
    this.textInputType
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
        controller: myController,
        keyboardType: textInputType,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        decoration: decoration
    );}}
```

**2nd Question. How to get textField value?**

In my button `onPressed()` method I called, I called `validation` method, But result is `null`

```
usernameValidation(){
  String username = UsernameTextField().usernameController.text;
  print(username);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert UsernameTextField class to a Stateful one by extending as a StatefulWidget instead of StatelessWidget.
Then you can get value from  `usernameController.text`

**UPDATE**

```
    class UsernameTextField extends StatefulWidget{
      final usernameController = TextEditingController();
      UsernameTextField(this.usernameController)

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return UsernameTextFieldState(usernameController);
      }
    }

    class UsernameTextFieldState extends State<UsernameTextField>{

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AppTextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              labelText: AppTranslations.of(context)
                  .text("loginpage_username"),
            ),
            myController: widget.usernameController,
            textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Okay I will try and let you know..what about Question 01. Do you answer for question 01?

Comment: Yes because the class where you defined TextEditingController its not a stateful widget. It will not save the state  ( the text you entered )

Comment: its usernameController.text; not UsernameTextField().usernameController.text;

Comment: how to get `State` class controller value?

Comment: @user9139407 have you fixed?

Comment: same result. result is `null`. my `UsernameTextField` pass `usernameController` variable to `AppTextField` class.  `AppTextField` return `TextFormField` widget. If I printed like this, it should be `null` right? because `UsernameTextField` delare just a variable. `print(UsernameTextField().usernameController.text;)`